# Функция, которая рисует таблицу умножения

Tags: php

Помогите правильно сделать вывод чисел.

функция должна нарисовать следующий результат

1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12

А у меня так не получается, как исправить?

```
function foo3($a,$b){
    for($i = 1; $i <= $a; $i++){
        for($t = 1; $t <= $b; $t++){

    }
        echo $i;
        echo $i * 2;
        echo $i * 3;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

foo3(4,3)

Answer (score 3):

- Закрывающая скобка второго цикла у вас не там была (получился холостой цикл).
- Т.к. вы пробегаетесь циклом со счетчиками не зря, то их и надо умножать. Иначе к чему все эти `echo $i; echo $i * 2; echo $i * 3;` ??? Я вот лично не понял.
- Т.к. вы хотите получить "перевернутый" вывод, то и пробегаться надо в начале циклом до значения `$b`, а вторым — до `$a`.
- Ну и отделять строки через `<br/>` только в первом цикле надо.

  ```
  function foo3($a,$b){
      for($i = 1; $i <= $b; $i++){
          for($t = 1; $t <= $a; $t++){    
              echo $i * $t.' ';               
          }

          echo '<br>';
      }
  }

  foo3(4,3);
  ```